# How to display tabular record of dates from date range

Tags: sql-server

I have Request table with 3 records having structure:  Id, DateFrom, DateTo

```
Id  DateFrom    DateTo
1   15/01/2019  15/01/2019
2   21/01/2019  28/01/2019
3   04/02/2019  09/02/2019

And I want an output like this:
Id  Date
1   15/01/2019
2   21/01/2019
2   22/01/2019
2   23/01/2019
2   24/01/2019
2   25/01/2019
2   26/01/2019
2   27/01/2019
2   28/01/2019
3   04/02/2019
3   05/02/2019
3   06/02/2019
3   07/02/2019
3   08/02/2019
3   09/02/2019
```

I have created a table valued function to display the series of date based DateFrom and DateTo.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvfhrms_Calendar_DateRange](@DateFrom date, @DateTo date)
RETURNS @DateOfTheYear Table(Level int,SysDate date)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH AllDays
          AS (  
                SELECT  [Level] = 1 
                ,[Date] = @DateFrom

                UNION ALL

                SELECT [Level] = [Level] + 1
                ,[Date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
                FROM     AllDays
                WHERE    [Date] < @DateTo 
             )
    INSERT @DateOfTheYear
    SELECT [Level]
    ,[SysDate]=[Date]
    FROM   AllDays OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
    RETURN
END
```

Then when used in select query,

```
SELECT sysdate from [dbo].[tvfhrms_Calendar_DateRange]('2019-01-10', '2019-02-09')
```

This will give the results of the sequence of Datefrom to DateTo.
How can I integrate this to my table so that I can have the output as my expectations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT tt.*
      FROM [dbo].[tvfhrms_Calendar_DateRange] (t.datefrom, t.dateto) AS tt
     ) tt;
```

Comment: This is really fast. Great!

Answer (score 1):

No need to have extra table with dates. Note that my dates in different format.

```
   DECLARE @t TABLE (Id INT, DateFrom DATE, DateTo DATE)
    INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    (1,'01/15/2019','01/15/2019'),
    (2,'01/21/2019','01/28/2019'),
    (3,'02/04/2019','02/09/2019')

;WITH cte as (
    SELECT ID, [Date] = DateFrom FROM @t 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.ID, DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date]) FROM @t as t
    INNER JOIN cte ON t.ID = cte.ID and cte.[Date] < t.DateTo
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY ID
```